# Represent XML content as NSData - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata

I have an external XML file which I want to be represented in an NSData object

I am doing this;

```
 NSError *error;
NSString* contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:&error];
NSData* xmlData = [contents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But for some reasons, I am getting an error (does not respond)

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have time to test this out but I think you may want to try looking into NSData's `dataWithContentsOfURL:` or `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` and get it directly as data.

Also, unless you just threw http://www.apple.com/ in as a placeholder, I don't believe the source of that page is valid XML. The following feed is valid xml: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds You could try that. with what you have now first and see if it works.

Hope this helps.

**Updated:**

Without my knowing your project, you may get some benefit from using TouchXML - https://github.com/mrevilme/TouchXML which handles XML very well including what you are trying to do:

```
CXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)inURL encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding options:(NSUInteger)inOptions error:(NSError **)outError];
```

Comment: Just tried that. It is also saying

+[NSString dataWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x20ed60

Also apple.com is just for placeholder..i m passing a URL which returns XML

Comment: Sry, I should have been clearer with my suggestion. I'm suggesting skip the string part. Go straight to NSData* xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]
];